# Importing a LibGDX project into Android Studio from an SVN repository

Tags: svn, android-studio, intellij-idea, libgdx

My friend gave me a link to his SVN repository to help him with his Android app. I would like to start working on it as soon as possible, but the problem is I have never worked with LibGDX or SVN before so I'm not sure how to import the project into Android Studio.

Would anybody be able to give me a quick walk-through on how to do this? I haven't had any luck - for example, when I try to use the svn command in cmd it doesn't recognise the command. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should read documentation on Subversion and Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA. Here is the instruction on how to checkout a working copy of a project from Subversion repository: [Checking Out Files from Subversion Repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/checking-out-files-from-subversion-repository.html).

To learn more about Subversion and version-control in general, read [SVNBook (Version Control with Subversion)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/index.html).

> when I try to use the svn command in cmd it doesn't recognise the
>   command.

This indicates that you don't have command-line Subversion client installed. If you want to work with Subversion from the command prompt, install the client first.